# how to upload file asynchronously in mvc with example without loading entire page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
 var formdata;
 formdata = new FormData();
 var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileToUploadinproposal');
 //Iterating through each files selected in fileInput
 for (i = 0; i < fileInput.fi.length; i++) {
     //Appending each file to FormData object
     formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
 }
 //Creating an XMLHttpRequest and sending
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('POST', "/Contract/UploadProposalDocument/");
 xhr.send("");
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
           debugger;
           if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                  $("#fileToUploadinproposal").val("")
                  alert(xhr.responseText);
           }
 }
 return false;
```

in client side formdata is not accepting    and fileInput.files.length also not accepting

Comment: [Ajax Multiple File Upload Script With Progress Bar, Drag And Drop Qq.FileUploader In Mvc 4 Razor](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2012/09/ajax-multiple-file-upload-script-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jquery plugin as i mostly use this asp.net mvc to upload file via ajax:

http://powerdotnetcore.com/asp-net-mvc/asp-net-mvc-simple-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery

or you can refer this tutorial i made and used it in some scenarios, it uses iframe to upload file:

http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/08/aspnet-mvc-ajax-file-uploading-using.html